# Job configuration for Synchronous query in Google Big Query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Can job configuration be done to allow Large results using Synchronous big query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, queries have a [maximum response size](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries). If you plan to run a query that might return larger results, you can set `allowLargeResults` to true in your job configuration. Jobs are objects that manage **asynchronous** tasks. So this is not possible in synchronous mode.

Queries that return large results will take longer to execute, even if the result set is small, and are subject to additional limitations:

- You must specify a destination table.
- You can't specify a top-level ORDER BY clause.
- Window functions can't return large query results.
- For larger data volumes, you can't use the TOP() function.

** Maximum response size: 128 MB compressed* (unlimited when returning large query results)